# Current transformer PCB interference

Tags: pcb, current-transformer

I'm planning to build a power monitor using an ESP32. The main function would be to control 8 outlets through 8 relays and to monitor the AC power consumed by every outlet with ZMCT103C current transformers and a MCP3208 ADC. As I'm planning to create a PCB, I was wondering how close the current transformers can be placed to each other on the PCB without interfering with each other?

Regards

Comment: Good question. Best to test 2 samples. One to measure current and other to measure crosstalk.  See this https://ctlsys.com/support/current_transformer_crosstalk/  Split Core are far superior.

Comment: I've found that they should be placed at right angles to each other. Even though they are a toroid, they do pick up stray fields.